# Bug in JavaScript Google Chrome console when printing object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, console.log

For some reason, printing an array of objects in console.log() doesn't print each object correctly.

When I loop through the array for each individual object and print its property I am interested in, it differs from the object being printed in the array. I performed this check before and after I print the array of objects with the check having matching property values while sometimes differing with the array.

What could be some reasons for this? I am happy to give more details but I'm not sure what is relevant to this problem.

```
for(let i = 0; i < activeMonsters.length; i++) {
    console.log("Before: " + i + "|" + activeMonsters[i].xPos);
    // console.log(activeMonsters[i]);
}
console.log(activeMonsters);
for(let i = 0; i < activeMonsters.length; i++) {
    // console.log(activeMonsters[i]);
    console.log(i + "|" + activeMonsters[i].xPos);
}
```

Comment: Share the code @HenryZhang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, `console.log()` works as per design.
If I understand correctly you want to see Objects in details for that use:

**Option 1:**

`console.dir()` to print browserable Object in chrome console.

For more information please check here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir

**Option 2:**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify());
```

This should also give you browserable Object.

Comment: So `console.log()` is only designed to work sometimes when printing objects?

Comment: @HenryZhang I mentioned console.dir() is to print object with its properties. Your question is too wague and difficult to understand. What do you mean by **sometimes differing with the array**. Add proper examples in question.

Comment: I'm just wondering why console.log() is inconsistent when printing objects. In the above example, xPos is an integer and the for loops sometimes print a different number than the xPos property of objects in the activeMonsters array.

Comment: Again, Information is not enough. What out are you getting on console? Better to add screenshots of both outputs. Maybe that is happening due to different input i.e. `activeMonsters` has different value.